# Filter data where value is shared by all groups

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, group-by

I'm probably having a brain fart, but what I'm trying to do is just `filter` groups for which `products` are common to all `class`es. I should note with my real data, I cannot hardcode `filter`. That is a `filter(product %in% c("apple","lemon")` will not work since I have thousands of products.

**Example Code Data**

Where `apple` and `lemon` are common to all `class`es

```
df <- data.frame(
  class = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
            "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
            "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  product = c("apple", "lemon", "banana"," orange", "papaya",
              "apple", "lemon", "lime", "blueberry", "raspberry",
              "apple", "lemon", "mango", "strawberry", "pear")
  )

df
   class    product
1      A      apple
2      A      lemon
3      A     banana
4      A     orange
5      A     papaya
6      B      apple
7      B      lemon
8      B       lime
9      B  blueberry
10     B  raspberry
11     C      apple
12     C      lemon
13     C      mango
14     C strawberry
15     C       pear
```

**Desired Output**

```
   class    product
1      A      apple
2      A      lemon
3      B      apple
4      B      lemon
5      C      apple
6      C      lemon
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there will not be duplicates within a group, see if below code works for you

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(product) %>% mutate(cnt = n()) %>% group_by(class) %>% 
   mutate(g = group_indices()) %>% ungroup() %>% 
   filter(cnt >= max(g)) %>% select(-cnt)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  class product     g
  <chr> <chr>   <int>
1 A     apple       1
2 A     lemon       1
3 B     apple       2
4 B     lemon       2
5 C     apple       3
6 C     lemon       3
```

Comment: The hardcoded `filter(cnt >= 3)` needed to be changed to account for all groups. Close though! For whatever reason `filter(cnt == length(unique(class)))` is not working for me even though the output is 3...

Comment: @TheSciGuy, have made change to my answer, please check if that works now.

Comment: Works great! Thanks!